why InAppWebView Page scroll not working in IOS Device?
InAppWebView(
                                  gestureRecognizers: Set()
                                    ..add(
                                      Factory<VerticalDragGestureRecognizer>(
                                          () =>
                                              VerticalDragGestureRecognizer()),
                                    )
                                    ..add(
                                      Factory<LongPressGestureRecognizer>(
                                          () => LongPressGestureRecognizer()),
                                    )
                                    ..add(
                                      Factory<ScaleGestureRecognizer>(
                                          () => ScaleGestureRecognizer()),
                                    ),
                                  initialOptions: InAppWebViewGroupOptions(
                                      crossPlatform: InAppWebViewOptions(
                                          javaScriptEnabled: true,
                                          preferredContentMode:
                                              UserPreferredContentMode.MOBILE,
                                          horizontalScrollBarEnabled: true,
                                          cacheEnabled: false,
                                          useOnDownloadStart: true),
                                      android: AndroidInAppWebViewOptions(
                                          verticalScrollbarThumbColor:
                                              Get.context!.theme.primaryColor,
                                          clearSessionCache: true,
                                          useWideViewPort: true,
                                          useHybridComposition: true),
                                      ios: IOSInAppWebViewOptions(
                                          enableViewportScale: true,
                                          alwaysBounceVertical: true)),
                                  onWebViewCreated: (controller) {
                                    webViewController = controller;
                                  },
                                  initialUrlRequest: URLRequest(
                                      url: Uri.parse("www.google.com"),
                                ))





IOSInAppWebViewOptions(
                                                        enableViewportScale: true,
                                                        alwaysBounceVertical: false,
                                                        scrollsToTop: false,
                                                        isPagingEnabled:true,
                                                        useOnNavigationResponse: true,
                                                        isDirectionalLockEnabled: true,
                                                    )

